# Javascript: Map string using regex and include only matched groups

Tags: javascript, regex, string, templating

I have some files that are named according to their content. Some files are single parts and some contain multiple parts. I cannot change this structure unfortunately.

Using JavaScript, I would like to use a regex to match the filename, and then use any matched groups to create a new filename. The regex itself only partially matches the filename.

For example:

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| MyTestString1-id1p01&p02.Part1And2.txt | 1-2. Part1And2.txt |
| MyTestString2-id1p03.Part3.txt | 3. Part3.txt |
| MyTestString3-id1p04.Part4.txt | 4. Part4.txt |

I tried using a regex to match the filename:
`(?:p(\d+))(?:&p(\d+))?\.(.+)\.`

This works and gives me the matches I want:

```
MyTestString1-id1p01&p02.Part1And2.txt -> [p01&p02.Part1And2., 01, 02, Part1And2]
MyTestString2-id1p03.Part3.txt -> [p03.Part3., 03, Part3]
MyTestString3-id1p04.Part4.txt -> [p04.Part4., 04, Part4]
```

However I can't find a nice way to then map to the string I want. I want something like
`$1-$2. $3`

But `string.replace` only replaces the matches, and still includes the rest of the string. So I end up with:
`MyTestString1-id101-02. Part1And2txt` instead of `1-2. Part1And2.txt`. Which makes sense, it's doing a replace where I need something more like a template.

And for others that don't have a second part I get:
`MyTestString2-id103-. Part3txt` which contains the `-` that I don't want.

Is there something similar to `string.replace` using only the replacement string? And is there a way to optionally include a separator for groups that may exist and exclude them if they don't?

Also note the filenames are much large than in my example, I just cut them short as I'm ignoring them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prefix your regex with `^.*` to match (and then discard) the prefix part of the original string.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work as it matches the first p01 before the &. So that first line match turns into this: `MyTestString1-id1p01&p02.Part1And2.txt -> [MyTestString1-id1p01&p02.Part1And2., 02, Part1And2]` missing the 01.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
p(\d+)(?:&p(\d+))?\.(.+\.[^.]*)$
```

See the JS demo code below:

```js
const texts = ['MyTestString1-id1p01&p02.Part1And2.txt', // 1-2. Part1And2.txt
'MyTestString2-id1p03.Part3.txt', //    3. Part3.txt
'MyTestString3-id1p04.Part4.txt'] //    4. Part4.txt
const re = /p(\d+)(?:&p(\d+))?\.(.+\.[^.]*)$/;
for (const s of texts) {
  const [_,num1,num2,filename] = re.exec(s)
  result = `${Number(num1)}` + (num2 ? `-${Number(num2)}. `:'. ') + filename;
  console.log(s, '=>', result);
}
```

Here is [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XEbaHl/1)

Note that `(.+\.[^.]*)$` matches and captures into Group 3 one or more characters other than line break chars, as many as possible and then a `.` and then zero or more chars other than  a `.` till end of string.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! Would it be possible to use some form of template string so that I can change it dynamically? Like the `$1-$2. $3` I was thinking about above? Ideally I'd like that to be configurable as I have other files that I might want to structure into a different format.

Comment: @Shifty JavaScript RegExp does not support conditional constructs inside replacement patterns, sorry. You will have to define specific replacements with functions, or the wayI used in the answer.